# Invoke Barcode Scanner from Browser on Android Device

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

So I've found a lot of examples of how to do this using http://zxing.appspot.com/scan, but it only seems to work on a select few devices.  I've gotten it to work on the HTC Evo View.  But on both the Samsung Galaxy Tab and ZTE Optik it just takes me to a page telling me I don't have the Zxing barcode app installed even though I do.  Has anyone else encountered this inconsistency and if so, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really up to the app, as I understand it, to interact with the platform to resolve the URL to something besides a web site. Some browsers do, some don't; I have certainly seen both behaviors, or different behaviors in different contexts -- typing the URL doesn't seem to trigger it for example.

I don't have any information myself on exactly which browsers do or don't fire an Intent, but I believe Chrome and derivatives do. I don't know exactly what's on the two that don't work.

I don't believe there's any way to force the behavior as the app can handle the link directly if it really wanted to and keep it away from any platform handler.

Comment: When you used the words "typing the URL doesn't seem to trigger" it got me thinking.  That was basically all I was trying to do.  But when I changed it up and included it as an <a href.../> or a button, it worked on both devices.